# Need to point "pdflatex" etc. to the official install rather than Apt install

Tags: ubuntu, linux, versions

I have just installed the texlive-full 2016 using install-tl on Ubuntu 16.04. I then installed TeXMaker, which appears to have installed the basic texlive 2015 version over the top of the 2016 commands that I want. For example

```
$ pdflatex --version 
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
```

Because of this version conflict nothing will compile (the pdflatex command can't find the 2016 .sty files etc.)

How do I tell my system to use the 2016 latex system?

```
$ locate -b '\pdflatex'
/usr/bin/pdflatex
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid installing texlive 2015 when you install TeXmaker. You have to tell apt not to install the recommended packages.

```
# apt-get --no-install-recommends install texmaker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5webkit5 libsynctex1 texmaker-data
Suggested packages:
  qt5-qmltooling-plugins
Recommended packages:
  texlive-lang-english asymptote
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5webkit5 libsynctex1 texmaker texmaker-data
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 59.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

This avoids installing texlive from the debian/ubuntu repo.

Alternatively, you can use equivs to create a dummy texlive package which "satisifies" the dependencies which require texlive* packages from the repo.

Comment: Might need to use sudo. Or, might need to download the package first, then install using dpkg. A few other packages will be needed, but not texlive. That's how I did it on Ubuntu 16.04 (in my case, the GUI I wanted was TeXworks).